# To create class-child of float which in case all arithmetic operations returns object of same class (not float)

Tags: python, oop

My class example:

```
class Ff(float):
    def __str__(self):
        return '{:.2f}'.format(self) + '$'

a = Ff(1)
print(type(a))
print(a)
```

Return:

```
<class '__main__.Ff'>
1.00$
```

But in case:

```
a = Ff(1) + 2
print(type(a))
print(a)
```

Return:

```
<class 'float'>
3.0
```

How to in case add `Ff(1) + 2` or for radd `2 + Ff(1)` get same <class '**main**.Ff'> in result?

Comment: Implement the `__add__` method and related methods to return your custom subtype…

Comment: yes, implement `__add__` to be abel to do `Ff(1) + 2`. but you also need to implement `__radd__` to be able to do `2 + Ff(1)`

Comment: I must override all arithmetic methods for this? Looks not so optimal.. In my case when I try implement __add__ I received: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. Have you example?

Comment: Yeah, you'll get into some awkwardness if you try to do `+` within `__add__` on two objects that override `__add__`… Subclassing `float` directly might not be a good idea for this reason. You may want to have a look at https://pypi.org/project/money/ for example.